# Titan Indexing With Elastic Search. String Matching Issue

Tags: elasticsearch, titan, tinkerpop3

I am having some trouble getting indexing to work with Titan. I configure my index as follows:

```
TitanGraph graph = TitanFactory.open("conf/titan-cassandra-es.properties");
TitanManagement management = graph.openManagement();
String indexKey = "byItemIdentifier";
String propertyKey = "ITEM_IDENTIFIER";
TitanIndex index = management.getGraphIndex(indexKey);
PropertyKey key = management.makePropertyKey(propertyKey).dataType(String.class).make();
management.buildIndex(indexKey, Vertex.class).addKey(key, Mapping.STRING.asParameter()).buildMixedIndex("search");
management.commit();
```

Now the problem:

```
Vertex vertex = graph.addVertex();
vertex.property(propertyKey, "www.foo.com/bar");
graph.commit();
```

Then later I try the following:

```
graph.traversal().V().has(propertyKey, "foo").hasNext(); //(1)
graph.traversal().V().has(propertyKey, "bar").hasNext(); //(2)
graph.traversal().V().has(propertyKey, "www.foo.com/bar").hasNext(); //(3)
```

**(1) = `false`**, **(2) = `false`** and **(3) = `false`**. How is this happening ? Surely **(3)** should return `true` ? Have I misconfigured something ?

Comment: Not an answer to your question, but do you actually need the mixed index? You can do equality tests with Titan's internal composite indexes. Personally, due to issue [788](https://github.com/thinkaurelius/titan/issues/788), I have gone out of my way to avoid mixed indexes.

Comment: @Ralf for now I have changed to using Composite Indexes and it is sufficient. Thanks for pointing out the issue.

Answer (score 0):

First, right after you create the index, you should wait for it to go from installed to registered. This method would help:

```
// Block until the SchemaStatus transitions from INSTALLED to REGISTERED
ManagementSystem.awaitGraphIndexStatus(graph, vertices_index).status(SchemaStatus.REGISTERED).call();
```

This blocks your code until your indexing backend creates it.

Second, if there is already some data in the graph, you MUST reindex your properties so the indexing backend (Elasticsearch, etc) could be aware of it. Use this Java method:

```
public static void reindexGraph(TitanGraph graph, String myIndex) throws InterruptedException {
    TitanManagement management = graph.openManagement();
    TitanGraphIndex index = management.getGraphIndex(myIndex);
    management.updateIndex(index, SchemaAction.REINDEX);
    management.commit();

    // Enable the index
    ManagementSystem.awaitGraphIndexStatus(graph, myIndex).status(SchemaStatus.ENABLED).call();
    graph.tx().commit();
}
```